# Is it possible to not load data first time on page load?

Tags: datatables

I'm using the [jquery DataTables](http://datatables.net) plugin.

Is it possible to not load data first time?

I will load data later with different filters applied.

Comment: I didn't work with jquery DataTables but you probably can check if there's a cookie (meaning - not the first time) - load data, and if not, don't load the data - plant a cookie ;)

Answer (score 11):

You could use the `deferLoading` Parameter and set it to `0`.
This will delay the loading of data until a filter or sorting action happens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferLoading": 0,
        "ajax": {
                url:"scripts/server_processing.php",
                'data': {
                        'dbName': 'willi'
                }
        }
    });
});
```

More Info [here](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html) (dataTables 1.10.0)